# How to do a generic call to function based on a Type object?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

how do you execute Get, when all you have is: T expressed as a Type object i.e.

```
Type type=typeof(int);
```

and arguments param1 and param2?

```
    public void DoCall(){
        var type=typeof(int);
        // object o=Get<type> ("p1","p2");   //<-- wont work (expected)
        // *** what should go here? ***
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string param1,string param2) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: This sort of generic method is for type safety at compile time. If you dont know the type at compile time there is a good chance you're using generics wrong, or should have an additional overload which takes the type as a parameter such as `public IEnumerable Get(Type type, string param1, string param2)`.

Comment: @Jamiec: thanks for the comment Jamiec.  I'll keep that in mind.  One reason to keep <T> is that I want to use <T> whenever possible.  I'd have to abandone <T> usage for this case, or adopt two method signatures (one with <T>, the other with Get(Type typ, ...)

Comment: @sgtz - having 2 methods is the *usual* way to deal with both possibilities. Its how most DA libraries handle this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use reflection:

```
public IEnumerable GetBoxed(Type type, string param1, string param2)
{
    return (IEnumerable)this
        .GetType()
        .GetMethod("Get")
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(this, new[] { param1, param2 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`MakeGenericMethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=makegenericmethod) is the key:

```
var get = typeof(WhereverYourGetMethodIs).GetMethod("Get");
var genericGet = get.MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

Comment: +1 That looks close.  Should we also provide args to "MakeGenericMethod"?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just using the generic type parameter directly?

```
public void DoCall(){
    IEnumerable<int> integers = Get<int> ("p1","p2");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example above the 'T' will be whatever you pass into the Get method and it will also return the same IEnumerable.  So if you do the following:

```
 IEnumerable<int> o = Get<int>("p1", "p2");
```

o will be IEnumerable

but if you want something else, then you just pass in a different Type, hence Generic types.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should redefine your Get method to take the type of object as an argument:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get(object type, string param1,string param2)
{
}
```

Then if you really need it, you can rewrite the original generic method as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string param1,string param2)
{
    var result = Get(typeof(T), param1, param2);
    return result.Cast<T>();
}
```